# I want to compare two video files using FFPLAY

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editor, signal-processing

One of those videos lower resolution, another one is higher

```
ffplay.exe -i [PATHTOFILE][org] -i[PATHTOFILE][enc];\
[org][enc]blend=all_mode=difference"enter code here
```

but i got error

```
    No such filter: [filename1][org][filename2][enc];
[org][enc]blend=all_mode=difference: Invalid argument
```

I Just want to compare my videos utilizing **FFPLAY** with many inputs to save some memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ffplay is designed to play a single input. So, a workaround is needed.

```
ffplay -f lavfi "movie=org[a];movie=enc[b];[a][b]blend=all_mode=difference"
```

A filtergraph is created and movie source filters used to open the files, then blended.

Comment: I got error Argument [filename]  provided as input filename, but [filename][a]; "  was already specified.

Comment: Add `report` to command and share report.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/bZdu5GL0 - report

Comment: The command has to be in the form in my answer: `ffplay -f lavfi "movie='C\:/Users/Lover/Desktop/video.wmv'[a];movie='C\:/Users/Lover/Desktop/video - Copy.wmv'[b];[a][b]blend=all_mode=difference"`

Comment: great! That works, is there any way how to create 2 ffplay windows to compare side by side? This blend mode doesn't help too much in my case. I can tell they different in terms of pixel peeping but i need full range of colors.

Comment: Instead of `blend=all_mode=difference` use `hstack`

Comment: I was aiming for! Thx a lot